# Concurrent incrementation of integer column on update with NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, concurrency, auto-increment, increment

I have a Posts table with a `Version` number column to keep track of the nth revision for each record. Every time a row is updated, I would like its `Version` number to be incremented.

Presently, I am incrementing the column in my application logic, but because `post.Version += 1;` does not equate to `UPDATE Posts SET Version = Version + 1...`, I am worried that two concurrent updates will result in only one Version increment.

Solving this is easy with a manual SQL expression (as above) or an update trigger, but I would rather have Fluent NHibernate take care of this for me, if possible.

Using a transaction for the update would not prevent two simultaneous reads from both seeing version "7", and both deciding that the next value should be 8. Thus, two updates to version 7 could result in a value of 8, instead of 9.

How do I design or map an auto-incrementing integer column that is concurrency-safe?

Comment: Maybe this topic is also worth checking, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362228/how-to-lock-objects-before-update-using-nhibernate-lock-modes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already baked into NHibernate. Check NH docs on `<version>` tag and on Optimistic Concurrency Control.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I found the `Version(x => x.Version);` mapping in Fluent NHibernate :)

Comment: beat me to it by a few seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you managing a Version column manually?

Use NHibernate's support for optimistic concurrency (see http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version) and you'll get that for free (along with a more correct behavior IMO)

Comment: Thanks (I'm new to NHibernate). I don't know how I ever used LINQ-to-SQL?!