# How to lock objects before update using NHibernate lock modes?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

So first let me state what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a table that is populated with jobs. And there is a web service with a method that allows for the alteration of job data called `SaveJob`. This method retrieves the job and all it's data, runs validations (which require some db queries of their own to other tables) on the new data and then saves it back to the database. It's somewhat slow. About a second.

What happens is occasionally two `SaveJob` calls will be made close together on the same job and they'll run over each other. Now currently this is the only web server but I would like to have my solution web farm compatible so even though I'm aware of how to solve this issue using a singleton I'd prefer to have the locks handled by the database.

The question is can I use NHibernate and SQL Server database locks to get a second SaveJob call to block when it tries to read a Job that is already being altered by another SaveJob call?

I believe the answer is yes but I'm not really sure how to go about it. I've read the documentation about the `ISession.Lock()` and I believe what I need is to use the `NHibernate.LockMode.Upgrade`

My next question is when is this lock released?

I assume that it is released when the transaction is committed but I can't find any documentation that explicitly states this.

However if that's the case then is there a way for me to open another transaction and run some queries without closing the transaction I've started when I grabbed the job in the first place? Or do I *have* to do this all in one transaction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I would advise against using a single transaction across multiple threads since the ISession itself is not thread safe.

When you use `LockMode.Upgrade` on the session, or on `session.Get()`, NHibernate will issue a `select with (rowlock)` statement (details might depend on database type and configuration) when you retrieve the entity. If the object was previously retrieved by another thread, the current thread will wait until the lock is released or the timeout expires. The lock itself is release when the `update` statement is executed on `transaction.Commit()`. Using `LockMode.UpgradeNoWait` offers similar functionality except it does not wait and simply fails when the lock is taken.

This [Ayende's post](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency) also has some info on what SQL NHibernate emits on `session.Lock()`.

You can read on the different types of locks on the [NHibernate Documentation Chapter 11, Section 6](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-locking).

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me more about how I can use multiple transactions in a single thread? Is that possible? Basically I need to get the Job and keep that transaction open and then I need to run some other queries on different tables. Is it possible for me to open a new transaction for this purpose?

Comment: First, the update should occur in a single transaction, which includes getting the object, updating the properties and calling update, or alternatively, you could call `session.Merge()` on the detached entity. In any case, you do not need multiple transactions for this. The validation though, I would do even before trying to update entity as it seems inefficient to grab an object only for the new update to fail validation.

Comment: One more thing,you shouldn't need a transaction to validate the object, but in either case, you should do it in a previous transaction, and then simply open a new session/transaction. You do not these opened for too long.

Comment: The validations I have to do on the job data require I made additional database get calls. Some of the validations are dependent on data in the DB. Can I "push" another transaction or start another without interfering with the Job get/edit transaction on the same thread?

Comment: You can open one transaction to retrieve the data needed for validation, close the transaction/session, (and like I said, you do not need a transaction for this, simply a session, although some might recommend using transactions on read-only operations), do the validation and then open another transaction to save the update.

Comment: You want to keep your transactions short and lean, with single operations, or few related ones. Maintaining a session/transaction opened does not provide meaningful performance gain, and yet might introduce stale data if the underlying tables change while running a validation for example.

Comment: Hi all, can you please help me out. I am facing similar problem. I am trying to save an entry in table tbl1 and then trying to select some data from same table. I am getting timeout expired error. What is alternative for this problem?

Comment: I would suggest you post a new questions and explain why this one does not help/apply your case; and also include what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens is occasionally two SaveJob calls will be made close together ...

These jobs point to the same database row or they are completely different entities?

If they point to one instance of job, you can use optimistic locking using `version` to forbid data rewrite.

If they are different, it's just point of database to allow concurrent query execution. `somehow slow` can be about table/index/identifier locking.

Locks are released no later than after a commit, depends on isolation lavel. Some (read) locks are released immediately after query execution, updates within specific row can be released after a commit.

EDIT:

Obviously optimistic locking is not good for you, you need to use

> //do a version check, using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, then reassociate:
>   sess.Lock(pk, LockMode.Upgrade);

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-update-lock

Comment: There's only a problem when they're the same entities. I've edited my question to clarify this.